# Why is 0 used as the critical number in this example for finding the extrema of a interval?

Tags: calculus

I came across this example of finding the critical numbers of a extrema on a interval [1,3] and was puzzled that why 0 was used as a critical number. The denominator $x^\frac{1}{3}$ is undefined if 0 was used, thus, it should not be in the domain of the function.

Can anyone explain why?

$f(x) = 2x-3x^{\frac{2}{3}}$

$f'(x) = 2(\frac{x^\frac{1}{3}-1}{x^\frac{1}{3}})$

The critical numbers were $x= 1, 0, -1, 3$

Comment: A [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) is by definition a point where $f'$ is zero or undefined.

Comment: zero **is** in the domain of $f(x)$ but it is **not** in the domain of $f'(x)$.

Comment: @Forester I forgot to mention that the interval is [1,3]

Comment: If the interval is $[1,3]$, then $-1$ is not in it... $1,3$ were selected as at the "edge" of the interval (the values $1,3$) there will be a local critical value ($1$ also happens to give $f'(1) = 0$). $0$ is chosen by definition (see azif00's comment)